# How to change webRTC audio bit rate in Firefox (51)

Tags: firefox, webrtc, sdp, bitrate

I have searched and searched but can not find a definitve answer to the question.

By default Firefox sets the bitrate for any audio sent via webRTC to 40 kbps. Changing the SDP parameter works in any other browswer supporting webRTC with the exception of Firefox (51).

This behavior is well documented in bug reports for years, but I can not find any solution/bug fix information for this.

Anybody with more information on this topic?

Comment: What SDP lines are you changing?

Comment: "b=AS:" is rewritten, the others stay the same. Works – as explained – in every browser (maybe even in Firefox now, I have not checked in years).